# Iterate over class inheritances in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, multiple-inheritance, crtp, fold-expression

Assume I have a some classes architecture (the number of the classes is growing up during the development time), that each class inherit from N classes with the same basic interface. What is the best way (if possible) to create a base function (in the base class OR in the derived class) that will iterate over the inheritances?

**Target:** Avoid developers mistakes and make sure we won't forget to call all the base functions from all of the inheritances & make the code more clear to read and understandable.

**Please see edit notes for updated state**

**Short Example:**

```
class shared_base {
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
}

class base_1 : virtual public shared_base {
public:
    void func() override {}
}

class base_2 : virtual public shared_base {
public:
    void func() override {}
}

class target : virtual public base_1, virtual public base_2 {
public:
    void func() override {
        // Instead of:
        base_1::func();
        base_2::func();
        // ... My func() implementation
        /*
        ~~TODO~~
        for_each(std::begin(inheritances), std::end(inheritances), [](auto& inheritance) -> void { inheritance::func(); })
        ~~TODO~~
        */
    }
}
```

**More descriptive & practical example:**

```
class base {
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
    /*...Some interface (pure virtual) functions...*/
}

class base_core : virtual public base {
public:
    void func() override {}
    /*...Some base implementations for the rest...*/

protected:
    template <typename FuncT>
    virtual void iterate_over_base_core_inheritances(FuncT function_to_apply) {
        /*~~TODO~~*/
    }
}

template <class Decorator = base_core, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<base_core, Decorator>::value>::type>
class core_1 : virtual public Decorator {
public:
    void func() override {
        // Will iterate (once) over Decorator
        /*iterate_over_base_core_inheritances([](core_base*) -> void {
            // Implementation
        });*/
        // Instead of:
        Decorator::func();
    }
    /*More functions implementations*/
}

template <class Decorator = base_core, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<base_core, Decorator>::value>::type>
class core_2 : virtual public core_1<>, virtual public Decorator {
public:
    void func() override {
        // Will iterate (twice) over core_1 and Decorator
        /*iterate_over_base_core_inheritances([](core_base*) -> void {
            // Implementation
        });*/
        // Instead of:
        Decorator::func();
        core_1::func();
        //... Self func() implementation
    }
    /*More functions implementations*/

protected:
    // If it's not possible doing it in the upper hierarchy level is it possible do it here?
    template <typename FuncT>
    void iterate_over_base_core_inheritances(FuncT function_to_apply) override {
        /*~~TODO~~*/
    }
}
```

**Some things to know:**

- I am working on Linux 64x platform (Ubuntu 16.04)- if it's matter for the answers.
- The idea behind this code is to create kind of Decorator DP, which will be easy to extend and to understand, and also will enable the developers to use the `protected` functions/attributes of the base class.

A **practical example** (for my actual use) can be found in [this commit](https://github.com/korelkashri/CppDecoratorDesignPattern/blob/20853d8dbeb8d767d1af5237f69c2861b496eaf8/src/main.cpp).

### Edit:

**[Thanks to @RaymondChen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen)** I got a working solution, with (so far) only one minor issue: Every time I want to use a class that implemented this way, I need to specify the `core_base` class in it's template arguments list (before- I was using the default type parameter). I am looking for a way to solve this issue.
**The current solution:**

```
template <class ...Decorators>
class core_2 : virtual public Decorators... {
public:
    static_assert((std::is_base_of<base_core, Decorators>::value && ...), "All decorators must inherit from base_core class.");

    void func() override {
        (Decorators::func(), ...);
        //... Self func() implementation
    }
    /*More functions implementations*/
}
```

Creating an instance example:
**Current:**
`std::shared_ptr<base> base = std::make_shared<core_2<core_1<base_core>, core_3<base_core>>>();`
**Desired:**
`std::shared_ptr<base> base = std::make_shared<core_2<core_1<>, core_3<>>>();`
A **practical example** (for my actual use) can be found in [this commit](https://github.com/korelkashri/CppDecoratorDesignPattern/blob/529a7a2216f0d498d34a163d8f27afcd2e968b6d/src/main.cpp).

Comment: `template<typename...inheritances> struct Decorator : virtual inheritances... { void func() override { (inheritances::func(), ...); } };`

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks a lot! Please post it as an answer.

Comment: That's okay, you can post the answer (and accept it) after fleshing it out. I don't need the imaginary points.

Comment: @RaymondChen After a lot of research, I been able to restore all of the functionality that I had without the variadic template (See edit section in my response). Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to [@RaymondChen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen)** I got really close to my original target with the following solution [**See update section at the bottom**]:

```
template <class ...Decorators>
class core_2 : virtual public Decorators... {
public:
    static_assert((std::is_base_of<base_core, Decorators>::value && ...), "All decorators must inherit from base_core class.");

    void func() override {
        (Decorators::func(), ...);
        //... Self func() implementation
    }
    /*More functions implementations*/
}
```

### Explanation:

Using parameters pack we can create a "list" of classes we inherit from, and using folding expression [c++17] we can implement it in just few lines of code.

### Pros compare to my original idea:

- The object creation line is more clear and logically now:
  **Before:**
  `std::shared_ptr<base> base = std::make_shared<core_2<core_1<core_3<>>>>();`
  **After:**
  `std::shared_ptr<base> base = std::make_shared<core_2<core_1<base_core>, core_3<base_core>>>();`
  Because core_1 & core_3 are independent, but core_2 is using both of them.
- No need of new function in the base/derived class, it's just fit within the target line (for example in `is_equal` function that didn't mention within this post).

### Lost functionality:

- *Template validation of `is_base_of`* (Solved with `static_assert` & `fold expressions`).
- Default inheritance in case that no inheritance specified is not possible yet (Still trying to solve).
  **Current:**
  `std::shared_ptr<base> base = std::make_shared<core_2<core_1<base_core>, core_3<base_core>>>();`
  **Desired:**
  `std::shared_ptr<base> base = std::make_shared<core_2<core_1<>, core_3<>>>();`

### Update

After a lot of research and tries, I came up with the following solution (improved also with C++20 `concepts` feature):

```
template <class T>
        concept Decorator = std::is_base_of_v<base_core, T>;

class empty_inheritance {};

template<typename Base = base_core, typename ...Decorators>
struct base_if_not_exists {
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof...(Decorators);
    using type = typename std::conditional<value, empty_inheritance, Base>::type;
};

template <Decorator ...Decorators>
class core_2 : virtual public base_if_not_exists<base_core, Decorators...>::type, virtual public Decorators... {
public:
    void func() override {
        if constexpr (!base_if_not_exists<base_core, Decorators...>::value) {
            base_core::func();
        }
        (Decorators::func(), ...);
        //... Self func() implementation
    }
    /*More functions implementations*/
}
```

No functionality lost :)

Comment: I don't see how this solution makes your code more easy to read?

Comment: @Moo-Juice compare to the originally way I suggested in the question to solve this issue, I don't need more functions/loops, just a single line of code `(Decorators::func(), ...)` or `return (Decorators::is_equal(...) && ...) && /*local function equality tests*/;`. Things that could easily get really complicated with an hierarchical function which accepts template function argument.