# How to pass a collection of functions to a client class to use as if they were members of the client class itself?

Tags: c++

I have the interface `IFuncs` with some methods (ideally these methods would be static, but I've found no good way to provide an interface to static methods - any suggestion?). This can be thought as a 'function collection'.

There is a class `Client` that internally uses a concrete implementation of that interface, passed at the construction.

Bellow, a code with the idea (don't compiles).

I would like to know suggestions of how to achieve this.

PS: It would be nice if the `Client` could call IFuncs (concrete) methods as if they were members of the `Client` class itself (as in the broken code bellow).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Interface for a class with some methods (ideally these methods would be static, but I've found no way to provide a interface to static methods)
class IFuncs {
public:
    virtual int fa(int a, int b) = 0;
    /* other functions */
};

// Implementation "X"
class FuncsX: public IFuncs {
public:
    int fa(int a, int b) {
        return a + 2*b;
    }
};

// Implementation "Y"
class FuncsY: public IFuncs {
public:
    int fa(int a, int b) {
        return 3*a - b;
    }
};

// alias for the type IFuncs::fa()
using fa_t = int (IFuncs::*)(int, int);

// Class that uses an implementation of IFuncs, passed to the constructor
class Client {
public:
    fa_t fa; // reference/pointer to a function IFuncs::fa()
    Client(const IFuncs& arg_funcs) : fa(arg_funcs.fa) {
    }

    void do_something(int a, int b) {
        // call fa() as it was a function member of this Class
        cout << fa(a, b) << "\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FuncsX funcsx;
    FuncsY funcsy;
    
    Client c1(funcsx);
    Client c2(funcsy);

    cout << c1.fa(3, 4) << "\n";
    cout << c2.fa(3, 4) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the functions are always going to be `static` why not just take a regular function?  That avoids any vtable overhead and probably fixes your problem (I'm guessing, since you didn't provide the compilation error).

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly different solution for you, which have pros & cons (this solution is for C++20 but if you need, it can simply converted into a C++11 one):

```
template<typename T> concept IFuncsInterface = std::is_base_of_v<IFuncs, T>; // Define a rule to force the type to inherit from IFuncs interface. If not it'll throw a compilation error.

// Class that uses an implementation of IFuncs, passed as template parameter
template <IFuncsInterface Funcs>
class Client : public Funcs { // Inherit from given type
public:
    Client() {}

    void do_something(int a, int b) {
        // call fa() as it was a function member of this Class
        cout << this->fa(a, b) << "\n"; // Working!
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Client<FuncsX> c1; // Inherit from FuncsX
    Client<FuncsY> c2; // Inherit from FuncsY

    cout << c1.fa(3, 4) << "\n";
    cout << c2.fa(3, 4) << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Pros

1. You don't have to create a pointer to each function in `IFuncs` interface.
2. Clean solution without a mess in the container function- you don't have to hold an object for every `IFuncs` child, that you want to create a `Client` of.

### Cons

1. It might be logically wrong, based on your classes purpose.
2. If you already have the `IFuncs` derived class somewhere, with defined properties that you want to use, with this solution you won't be able to apply them into the `Client` class (unless you'll implement some kind of set function).

### References

I implemented something like this lately, and you can see my ideas there: [CppDecoratorDesignPattern](https://github.com/korelkashri/CppDecoratorDesignPattern/blob/master/src/main.cpp) (it's not really a decorator design pattern, but it was close enough for me :P). To get this working, I got help from [@RaymondChen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) in the following post, which you can get more ideas from: [Iterate over class inheritances in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091515/iterate-over-class-inheritances-in-c).